# How to add wordpress filter to search?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to filter my search result in wordpress.
Does it exist a filter like **add_filter('search_result', 'xxxx')** ?

When I get the result, I need to apply a second custom filter...

I found this **add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );** It loops on result but i don't know how to remove an item...

Any idea ? thanks

Comment: What do you want to filter out?

Comment: According to the search, I have a web service that will allow or not some pages.